# Marketing cloud : Difference Between tracking count and Dataview count

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a email sent.
For the same i go to Tracking and see amount bounce = 188 (23 hard bounce and 165 soft bounce). How ever when i check the data view using the following sql , i get 190 record.

```
Select 
    T1.SubscriberKey
From 
    _bounce T1
Where 
    T1.JobID='756xxxx'
```

I dont know the reason why there can be difference between tracking screen and _bounce
The above actions i am doing in child BU

Comment: My guess would be a false bounce https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=False-Bounces-in-Marketing-Cloud&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks a lot EazyE. i think this is right answer , will wait for salesforce to confirm as i need to close defect for client , but your response makes complete sense to me. Thanks a lot

Comment: is it possible to identify such fake bounces and remove them from sql so that we get results as tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some info direct from SF Support:
As per the internal resources we have there are 5 categories for bounce types,

- HardBounces
- SoftBounces
- BlockBounces
- TechnicalBounces
- UnknownBounces

As below bounce categories are NOT included in reports:

- TechnicalBounces
- UnknownBounces

whereas in the `_BOUNCE` data view, it pulls in **all** bounces and is therefore a larger number.